# Creating a decorator depends with the kwargs argument as parameters

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a code:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs["name"] # Should display Dean Armada
        print 'Calling decorated function'
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@my_decorator(name="Dean Armada")
def example():
    """Docstring"""
    print 'Called example function'

example()
```

What I want to achieve is for my decorator to depend on the kwargs arguments as all of its parameter.. My code above throws this error

```
my_decorator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Comment: Create another (outer) layer that accepts a `name` argument, and pass that on to `wrapper`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have separate arguments for your decorator in the following way:

```
from functools import wraps


def my_decorator(**decorator_kwargs):  # the decorator
    print decorator_kwargs['name']

    def wrapper(f):  # a wrapper for the function
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):  # the decorated function
            print 'Calling decorated function'
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_function
    return wrapper


@my_decorator(name='Dean Armada')
def example(string):
    print string


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example('Print this!')
```

Running this produces the output:

```
Dean Armada
Calling decorated function
Print this!
```

Also note that `decorator_kwargs` is accessible from `wrapper` and `decorated_function` as well if needed.